# Split string into spaces of choice using split.( " ", int )

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

My code so far:

```
firstname = 'Christopher Arthur Hansen Brooks'.split(' ',1) # [0] selects the first element of the list
lastname = 'Christopher Arthur Hansen Brooks'.split(' ')[-1] # [-1] selects the last element of the list
print(firstname)
print(lastname)
```

I want output of:

```
['Christopher Arthur Hansen', 'Brooks']
```

I want that output by only using the `split(' ', int)` method. How can I do it?

Comment: So you want to split from the right? Have you considered [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)?

Comment: I think you want a comma.  `['Christopher Arthur Hansen', 'Brooks']`

Answer (score 2):

You could get that output by using `rsplit` and performing only one split, i.e:

```
'Christopher Arthur Hansen Brooks'.rsplit(' ', 1)
```

Which returns a list:

```
['Christopher Arthur Hansen', 'Brooks']
```

That you can unpack into `firstname` and `lastname`:

```
firstname, lastname = 'Christopher Arthur Hansen Brooks'.rsplit(' ', 1)
```

For input that might be short (i.e user only enters first name) it is better to use `rpartition` if you also want to unpack; the unpacking simply must handle the 3-element tuple returned:

```
firstname, _, lastname = 'Christopher Arthur Hansen Brooks'.rpartition(' ')
```

Comment: Or even `.rpartition(' ')` if a fixed result is required for cases where there's an empty string, or no split can be made etc...